# TensorFlow, Keras - TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'labels' has DataType float32 not in list of allowed values: int32, int64

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

The code below is giving `TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'labels' has DataType float32 not in list of allowed values: int32, int64`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
#tf.enable_eager_execution()
vocab_size=100
embedding_dim=256
seq_len=10
model=tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=seq_len))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size))
model.compile(optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1.0),loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy)#tf.keras.metrics.sparse_categorical_crossentropy
```

The error is avoided by any one of the following three actions:

1. execute `tf.enable_eager_execution()` after importing tensorflow
2. change `tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy` to `tf.keras.metrics.sparse_categorical_crossentropy`
3. remove the `tf.keras.layers.Embedding` layer

Any insights into this interaction between Keras Embedding layer and tf.losses will be greatly appreciated! I am using TensorFlow version 1.12.0.

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same issue and cannot really figure out how eager execution influences its origin.